# Do I need closure for every single methods that has a wait-for-result callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I was working on a nodejs server with socket.io and MySQL database when I realized that data may change anytime when data retrieval is slow from database.
Let's say for example, on each socket connection, I want to query the database for user's information when they emit X data.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('User connected');
    socket.on('fetchTable', function(data) {
        var number = data.number;
        database.getTable(number, function(error, result) {
            // We'll take it that result is constant for both: 1
            socket.emit('fetchTableResult', result + number);
        });
    });
});
```

If 2 users were to connect at the **same time** (user 1's number: 1, user 2's number: 2), user 1 requested for database **BEFORE** user 2 but the database was to return the results too slowly for user 1 and **processed user 2's data first**. Will the data returned be different? Both users will get '3' as the 'fetchTableResult' data right? And won't the socket now be both user 2's socket?

Solution?

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('User connected');
    socket.on('fetchTable', function(data) {
        var number = data.number;
        (function(socket, number) {
            database.getTable(number, function(error, result) {
                // We'll take it that result is constant for both: 1
                socket.emit('fetchTableResult', result + number);
            });
        })(socket, number)
    });
});
```

If that's the case, what if inside `database.getTable`, I have another method like fetching a website's HTML content that is going to take some time, do I exactly need another closure inside?

For example:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('User connected');
    socket.on('fetchTable', function(data) {
        var number = data.number;
        (function(socket, number) {
            database.getTable(number, function(error, result) {
                // We'll take it that result is constant for both: 1
                (function(socket, result) {
                    // fetch website html data
                    socket.emit('fetchTableResult', result + number);
                })(socket, result)
            });
        })(socket, number)
    });
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/loverajoel/jstips/blob/gh-pages/_posts/en/2016-02-03-implementing-asynchronous-loops.md

Comment: you don't need the closure in the second code block

Comment: @JaromandaX Do you mind explaining why? Is it because I'm already in my current scope and nothing else can change the value of `socket` and `result`?

Comment: sounds like you know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first example should work fine. See this for example:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var x = event.x;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(x);
  }, 1000);
});
```

Try clicking in two different places in a short time. As expected, you will get different results.

---

You need a closure (actually an IIFE) when you're executing an asynchronous function in a loop, for example, this won't work as expected:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 1000*i);
}
```

You have to either wrap it IIFE, like this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i);
    }, 1000*i);
  }(i));
}
```

or bind `i` to the callback, like this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(i) {
    console.log(i);
  }.bind(null, i), 1000*i);
}
```

<sub>Personally I like the second approach more.</sub>

However, when you are calling an asynchronous function many times, you don't need an IIFE, because this function is a closure itself. For example:

```js
function test(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 1000*i);
}

test(0);
test(1);
```

Every time `test()` is called, another scope is created, so the `i` variable isn't overwritten and it works as expected.